# How to check if string value from URL exists in Enum and assign its value in result to variable?

Tags: c#, enums

I want to check if the part of my urlPath **WEB** contains in the Enum and if yes to return its value in another variable.

```
    var urlPath = "SomeThing/Web";

    private enum ClientTypes
        {
            Mob = 0,
            Web = 1
        }

     var client = urlPath.Contains(ClientTypes.Any()) // something like this
```

How to check if the Web part from the url exists in the Enum and return its value and assign it to **client** property?

Comment: you need to dissect your url and use the [Enum.Pase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.parse?view=netframework-4.8) method, or even better use the [TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.tryparse?view=netframework-4.8) method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could Split the Url based on "/" and Compare with Enum Names. For Example,If you are only interested to know if Enum exists, you could use

```
var enumNames = Enum.GetNames(typeof(ClientTypes));
var result = urlPath.Split('/').Any(x=> enumNames.Contains(x));
```

If you want to retrieve the particular Enum, then you could use

```
var client = Enum.Parse(typeof(ClientTypes), urlPath.Split('/')
                                                    .FirstOrDefault(x=> enumNames.Contains(x)));
```

If there are more than one occurrence and you want to retrieve all of them, you could use

```
var clients = urlPath.Split('/')
                     .Where(x=> enumNames.Contains(x))
                     .Select(x=> Enum.Parse(typeof(ClientTypes),x));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make a generic method to split the url and try to convert each part into an enum value. This would be independent of your enum type. You can define the enum type at the call of this method. As already mentioned in my comment [Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.8#System_String_Split_System_Char___) the string and use [TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.tryparse?view=netframework-4.8) to convert the string to an enum value

```
public IEnumerable<TEnum> TryParseUrlToEnum<TEnum>(string url) where TEnum : struct, IConvertible
{
    foreach (var element in url.Split('/'))
    {
        if (Enum.TryParse<TEnum>(element, out TEnum enumValue))
        {
            yield return enumValue;
        }
    }
}
```

You would call it this way:

```
var urlPath = "SomeThing/Web";
List<ClientTypes> enumValues = TryParseUrlToEnum<ClientTypes>(urlPath).ToList();
```

This would also allow you to parse multiple occurences within the url:

```
var urlPath = "SomeThing/Web/somethingElse/Mob";
List<ClientTypes> enumValues = TryParseUrlToEnum<ClientTypes>(urlPath).ToList();
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, enumValues));
```

Output:

> Web
>   Mob